# Accessing Parent Class' Property From Derived Class

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm new to python and GAE and I thought python will act as any other OO language, but apparently not. How does *`__`init`__`(self):*  function gives me different results in the following code?

```
class BaseHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    @property
    def current_user(self):
        if not hasattr(self, "_current_user"):
            self._current_user = None
            cookie = facebook.get_user_from_cookie(self.request.cookies, FACEBOOK_APP_ID, FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET)
            user = User.get_by_key_name(cookie["uid"])

        return self._current_user

class SubmitHandler(BaseHandler):
    template_values = dict(facebook_app_id=FACEBOOK_APP_ID)

    def __init__(self):
        #throws error : AttributeError: 'SubmitHandler' object has no attribute 'request'
        self.template_values['current_user'] = self.current_user

    def get(self):
        #this one function is error free
        self.template_values['current_user'] = self.current_user
```

How do I access the class' parent property?

Comment: Do you need to call RequestHandler's `__init__` method to get the request variable set up?

Comment: I'm sorry Kristo, I don't really understand your question. But it seemed that I did not?

Answer (score 3):

If you look at your `SubmitHandler` class you'll notice that it indeed does not have a `request` attribute -- at least, none you set, and none you give the parent class a chance to set. Perhaps what you need to do is call the parentclass `__init__` method before you try to access `self.current_user`.

As a side note, you should realize that the `template_values` dict you define inside the `SubmitHandler` class there is a *class attribute*, and thus shared between all instances of the class. Since you assign it something instance-specific in your `__init__`, you probably mean for it to be an instance attribute instead. Assign it to `self.template_values` in your `__init__` method.

Comment: But why does it just work when I access it from get(self) function while it doesn't work from `__`init__(self) function? Also noted on the instance attribute, I will move the declaration inside the `__`init__ function.

Comment: `__init__` is a regular method, it just gets called very early in an object's lifetime (right after it's been created.) If it doesn't exist in `__init__` but it does exist later, the attribute apparently gets set by something that executes *after* `__init__`.

Comment: Nevermind, I think @Daniel Roseman answer above about _"you're failing to take into account the possibility that self.request is initialized at another point in the program"_ is make sense. I guess I have to create another function and call it from get and post function to setup the self.template_values dict. Or do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing particularly different about Python's object inheritance.

By defining `__init__`, you have told Python that this is all that needs to be done to initialize the object. You're therefore denying it the chance to run the superclass's initialization code. You need to call `super`:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(SubmitHandler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.template_values['current_user'] = self.current_user
```

This might however not solve your problem - you're failing to take into account the possibility that `self.request` is initialized at another point in the program, which is why it works by the time `get` is called.

Comment: I think you're right about _self.request is initialized at another point in the program_. However, if self.request is initialized at `__init__` of the parent class, it should be accessible on SubmitHandler '__init__` after I call the  `super(SubmitHandler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)` right? Am I making the correct assumption here?

Answer (score 0):

`self.request` and `self.response` are not set by the class constructor in webapp. They're set later, when the framework calls the handler's `initialize` method. You can override this, just make sure you call the parent class's `initialize` before doing anything else.